Meaning/origin of the German term "Schließungssatz" in geometry
Certain theorems in geometry are called Schließungssatz in German, like the theorem of Desargues and the theorem of Pappos, see for example this German wikipedia page.
I wonder what the (historical?) reason is for the part Schließung.
The German verb schließen has at least two possible meanings:

to deduce, so it would be "deducing theorem" which is kind of redundant. But maybe it is for historical reasons.
to close. Maybe the background is that the theorem guarantees some kind of "closedness" of the geometrical constellation, like three points being collinear in the case of Desargues and Pappos.

But these are only my personal guesses. Does anyone have a more profound explanation?
Addition
In his exceptional investigation below, Georg Essl identified this article by Hermann Wiener (published 1892, written 1890/91) as the likely earliest source of the term Schließungssatz.
This reduces my question to understanding why Wiener chose the term Schließungssatz.—Which meaning did he think of? Which picture did he have in mind?
I studied the Wiener's article a bit. Unfortunately, no direct reason for the choice is given. He introduces the term in the context of an axiomatic foundation of geometries:

Oder, vom geometrischen Gewande losgelöst: es seien Elemente von zweierlei Art vorausgesetzt, und zweierlei Operationen, indem man annimmt, dass die Verknüpfung je zweier Elemente derselben Art ein Element der anderen Art ergebe. Die geometrischen Sätze, die hierbei auftreten – wenn man von den auf die Anzahl der Elemente sich beziehenden combinatorischen Sätzen absieht – sind Schließungssätze, worunter hier solche Sätze zu verstehen sind, in denen jede in dem Satze vorkommende Gerade wenigstens drei ebensolche Punkte trägt, und jeder Punkt auf wenigstens drei Geraden liegt.

(For the English translation, see the answer of Georg Essl).
Both possibilities I stated above do make sense in this setting. But maybe one should try to understand Wiener's "definition" (which is not a precise definition in modern terms). It's not entirely clear, but he might have thought about starting with a few points and lines and then repeatedly applying his operations (connecting two points, intersecting two lines) to create more points and lines. At a certain point you might reproduce a point or line you already had, revealing a dependency among these operations. This is what I think he means by geometrische Sätze (engl. geometric theorems) and then by Schließungssatz. So in this sense a Schließungssatz

closes the territory of points and lines in the sense that you can't go any further applying the operations. (You won't get anything new.)

closes two chains of applications of his operations when they lead to the same point or line.


Both these interpretations make perfect sense to me.
Old addition (not too relevant any more, but kept for completeness)
There is the term closure theorem in English. However, my impression from an internet search is that the English closure theorem is used exclusively in Poncelet's closure theorem. This theorem can be interpreted that some sequences of linked line segments literally close, meaning that after a certain number of steps, you get back to the starting point.
Poncelet's closure theorem is also called Schließungssatz in German, and the German wikipedia article states "Der Satz ist das Paradebeispiel für eine Klasse geometrischer Probleme, die Schließungsprobleme genannt werden." ("The theorem is the prime example of a class of geometric problems called closure problems.")
So maybe Poncelet's theorem is the source of the term closure theorem in English and Schließungssatz in German. Unlike Enlish, the German term Schließungssatz got applied to a wider variety of geometric theorems of "similar flair". But again, this is only my private theory.
Comment
I had asked this question before on MSE, but did not get an answer. It was recommended that I post the question  here on HSM, which is what I'm doing now. Let's see if it makes a difference!

A full explanation of the concept appears here and runs to multiple pages in the process of explaining different variants. This is in German, and since it is outside my area of expertise I don't think I am capable of translating it into proper English terminology.

Historical aspects of the development of the term Schließungssatz can be found in:

Volkert, K. (2015). Hilberts Weg zu den „Grundlagen der Geometrie “.
In David Hilbert: Grundlagen der Geometrie (Festschrift 1899), Springer, 41-73.

Volkert identifies (see p.52f and footnote 37):

Wiener, H. (1890). Ueber Grundlagen und Aufbau der Geometrie.
Jahresbericht der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung, 1, 45-48.

as the first source to define Schließungssatz. (Incidentally this work can be viewed as the founder of the axiomatization of geometry, compare Scriba, C. J., & Schreiber, P. (2015). 5000 years of geometry, Birkhäuser. p. 502) Wiener writes p. 46 (my translation, any emphasis is mine):

We find such an example in the projective geometry of the plane. The
objects are points and lines, the operations are connecting and
intersecting; objects and operations are presumed to have a finite
count. Or, detatched from the geometric dressing: assume elements of
two kinds, and two operations, where one assumes that the combination
of two elements of the same kind results in an element of the other
kind. The geometric theorems, which appear in this form - if one
ignores the number of elements counted by combinatorial theorems - are
Schließungssätze which are understood to be theorems such that for each in a theorem occuring line contains at least three points, and
that each point lies on at least three lines.

Volkert credits the earliest "modern" definition of the term Schließungssatz to Vahlen (who later became one of the more disturbing Nazi mathematicians, compare Segal (2003). see also Volkert's discussion of Vahlen's attempt to diminish the contributions of his predecessors in particular Hilbert (Volkert, K. (2015). Die Rezeption der Hilbertschen „Festschrift “. David Hilbert: Grundlagen der Geometrie (Festschrift 1899), p. 200ff):

T. Vahlen (1905) Abstrakte Geometrie. Teubner.

These are theorems in affine and projective geometry regarding points and lines, and planes. Schließungssatz is defined on p. 62 as follows (my translation):

A statement, that one can recover via two differing constructions
starting from the same basis elements (points, lines, planes) recover
the same resulting elements (points, lines, planes) is called
"Schließungssatz". The totality of elements, which can be constructed
from the given basis elements, is called the "Netz" of these basis
elements.

As Volkert points out, the nomenclature was not universally accepted initially. While some (see Hölder (1908) and Zeuthen (1915)) adopted the terminology, others did not and stuck with Hilbert's "Schnittpunktsätze" (intersection point theorems) , see his Grundlagen, for example Mougang (1931). One English nomenclature is "composition theorem" as used by Hall (1943) (compare footnote 1, p. 26 in Pickert (1975) Projektive Ebenen, Springer.). I have not attempted to identify a point of broad adoption but it seems that today Wiener/Vahlen's terminology has succeeded in being adopted (compare Grinberg (2004) and sources therein).
While "closure theorems" is a suggestive translation and found in contemporary literature (compare Fomin and Pylyavskyy (2023)) one can even in contemporary literature find varying translations of the notion. For example Protasov (2011) uses "closing theorems".
In closing (pun intended) a brief word on German language use and meaning of schliessen and Schluss. Schluss in German both means deduce, close, and end, but these are related meanings. Einen "Schluss ziehen" (to draw to a close) would translate as "to deduce", while "einen Schluss finden" (to find a close) can sensibly be translated as "coming to a close". "Schluss machen" (make it end) would translate to "end it". The difference here is between the state and the process. Schliessen is the process of coming to a "schluss". i.e. loosely deduction is like coming to a close in an argument. If I had to guess there are etymological roots of literal (schliessen) closing of a door or lock. In German we call a lock "Schloss". And we indeed call closing a door "Tuer schliessen". If you can validly close a lock you properly came to a close and we can deduce that it is indeed closed. Compare Schluss.

Many thanks for this (+1) answer. It perfectly explains the origin of the term "Schließungssatz", and I'm really impressed how quickly you came up with this. But there is still the question for the meaning. Why did Wiener use the term "Schließung", which image did he have in mind doing so? You say your guess is more the English "close" than "deduce", and intuitively I tend to agree. It would be great if there was some historical note confirming this.

You write that "Volkert credits the earliest "modern" definition of the term Schließungssatz to Vahlen". The restriction "modern" might indicate that "Schließungssatz" had been used even before Vahlen, probably in a more intuitive and less formal way. Given the age of the theorems of Desargues and Pappos, I would not be surprised.

@azimut To be clear it is Wiener who coined the term in 1890, Vahlen merely expanded the scope of what it defines. I have no evidence of prior use. Wiener makes no mention of a potential motivating source. While Cantor did use "abgeschossene Menge" in 1885 but this is not exactly close nomenclature. In short I know of no direct evidence of a prior use or derivative connections and there is a chance the term is original to Wiener.

ok thanks for making this point clear. So apparently it really was Wiener who "invented" the term. I also doubt that there is a connection to "abgeschlossene Menge", both from linguistic ("Abschluss vs. Schließung") and semantic point of view.

Based on your insights, I've updated my question a bit, giving two new ideas about the interpretation of the term "Schließung".


Which meaning did he think of? Which picture did he have in mind?

While the actual content is outside my area of expertise, after a short search I would assume the following:
There is the german phrase "Der Kreis schließt sich" (roughly "the circle closes", maybe better "the cycle closes") that is used to describe that a chain of facts or circumstances relate to each other in a way that you find one again that you already encountered before, leading to all of them forming a cycle of chain elements.
In a similar way it seems to me that your first interpretation should be the correct one:


closes the territory of points and lines in the sense that you can't go any further applying the operations. (You won't get anything new.)


I found this document published via the LMU https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/Dreigeom/SchlEG.pdf.
I have no idea how sound that source work of that document is, but it explains Schließungssätze as being constructed in a way that after a fixed number of steps they close by leading back to the beginning of the first step:

...das sind Sätze, in denen es um Streckenzüge geht, die nach bestimmten Regeln konstruiert werden, und von denen behauptet wird, daß sie sich stets nach einer bestimmten Anzahl von Strecken schließen.

If that is not completely wrong, the picture of the closing cycle seems to be the inspiration for using Schließung.

Many thanks for this answer. My impression is that in the linked article, the term "Schließungssatz" is used only in the narrow sense that some geometrical figure literally closes. Like in the theorem of Poncelet, where also in English "closure theorem" is used. So could that have been the motivation to use "Schließungssatz" also in a wider sense? I had speculated a bit about that in the (old) addition to my question.

But with the insights of Georg Essl tracing back the usage of "Schließungssatz" to an article by H. Wiener in 1890 in the context of axiomatic geometry (and not narrow sense closing configurations), I pretty much doubt that.
